# Unity detect collision on drop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a drag and drop system, where the object which i'm dragging, will stick to certain location when dropped on them, otherwise automatically go back to the original location.

```
public Vector3 dist;
public Vector3 startPos;
public float posX;
public float posY;
public GameObject TopLeftUnfilled;
public GameObject TopRightUnfilled;
public GameObject BottomleftUnfilled;
public GameObject BottomRightUnfilled;
public int count1;
public int count2; 
public int count3;
public int count4;
public bool collided = false;

void Awake()
{
    startPos = gameObject.transform.localPosition;  
}

void OnMouseDown(){
    dist = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    posX = Input.mousePosition.x - dist.x;
    posY = Input.mousePosition.y - dist.y;

}

void OnMouseDrag(){
    Vector3 curPos = 
        new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - posX, 
            Input.mousePosition.y - posY, dist.z);  

    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curPos);
    transform.position = worldPos;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (collided)
    {
        foreach (Transform childTopLeft in TopLeftUnfilled.transform) 
        {
            count1++;
            if (count1 == 4) 
            {
                gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-2.3f, 1.195f, 0f);
            } 
            else
            {
                gameObject.transform.localPosition = startPos;
            }
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "TileUnfilled") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("collision");
        collided = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    collided = false;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I am now only testing this out with the upper-left unfilled area, but the collision is not detected. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Unity in front of me to test but I'm pretty sure

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
```

should be

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
```

Comment: Do your colliders have Rigidbodies?  From Unity Docs: "Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody attached."   And for OnCollisionEnter at least one of the Colliders must have a non-kinematic Rigidbody attached.